# Using GridSearchCV for custom kernel SVM in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I would like to use scikit-learn's [`GridSearchCV()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to do a grid search on custom parameters in a kernel I have specified. Specifically, the kernel is of the form

```
SeqKernel(x, y, orig_kernel, cut_off, order)
```

Here, `orig_kernel` is a kernel typically used in SVM learning (such as linear, polynomial, RBF, or sigmoid). I wish to perform a grid search over values of `cut_off` and `order`, with the additional caveat that only the pairs such that `order` $\le$ `cut_off` are considered. What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source code and modify it to meet your conditions.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L685